# Reporting server hide and bottom border of a row

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have a problem with strange rendering of a report in reporting server 2005 (the project is a bit old). In the first cell of the data row bottom border is hidden. The whole row is set to border solid. The report is rendered properly in any export format that I tried (excel, pdf, web archive).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgfGT.png)

Comment: Take a look at the properties on the actual textbox within the table. It might be overriding the row properties. See if it is set to solid, black color.

Comment: it is solid and black, I thought for that. Only in html is rendering wrong.